# More than just EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

Is there a more detailed error to be found other than the console's EXC_BAD_ACCESS? Where/how can I see it?

When my app crashes, I see the error in thE XCode status bar, but the console shows nothing else. Where do I see more info about what causes the crash?

Comment: Run it from Xcode and look at the call stack?

Comment: @Georg - Where can I find the call stack?

Comment: @Moshe: In the debug view, *Run->Debugger*.

Comment: @Georg- The Debugger shows nothing legible. Ugh. Thanks though.

Comment: Not a very well written question really, and it indicates that you didn't do much other than (a) have problem, (b) post one liner on stackoverflow. The answer is quite good.

Comment: picture of the call stack window:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/chitsaou/3355490739/

Comment: @WarrenP - Actually, no. I've seen this error before. Your personal adoration for the said "zombie technique" does not make it good. It makes it a personal favorite. Thanks  for an undeserved down vote. The question is not unclear or not useful. I do like the screenshot though. Thanks.

Comment: By bad question I merely mean, "could you have expanded a bit on that question so it was more clear".

Comment: An example of context: "When I am writing my application which fluxes the grill-covers of my foobender, I usually have the following windows open in XCode (list them), and I see the following (list it), and do not see the other things (list them) that I want to see.".  How do I click on the pull down menus to open other things that I want to see?

Comment: @Warren P - I suppose, but I don't think I was all that unclear that warranted a down vote. Whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application will have a stack trace, typically in the crash logs. Definitely look there for a bit more detail. Look under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter for those details. In general, run the application "Console.app" in your Utilities folder, and click on the button "Show Log List". It gives a detailed view into all the logs available that you'd likely want to check out in your system

If it's code you have written, the debugger (gdb) is the "how" to go to look for more detail. That's typically a "you overreleased" some object if you're working in Objective-C. There's [a good set of notes on using the technique "NSZombieEnabled"](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled) to find what you're blowing up on.

Comment: I love the zombie technique.   :-)